# AngularJS - Model not updating following async call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I was wondering if someone could help me? I am still pretty new to angular and having an issue whereby my select control is not choosing the correct value initially but updates on subsequent changes.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="job.SalutationId" ng-init="job.SalutationId=0">
    <option value="0">Salutation</option>
    <option ng-repeat="salutation in lookups.salutations" value="{{salutation.Id}}">{{salutation.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

I am loading an object via WebApi that represents a job and the lookup values at present - this isn't currently in a service as its all tests at present but the js looks like:

```
function loadJob() {
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: url + 'jobs/2' }).
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.lookups.salutations = response.data.Salutations;
            $scope.job = response.data.Job;  
        }, function (response) {
            displayJobErrorMessage(response.data || "Request failed");
        });
}
```

The HTML control is populated with the values from the lookup, `job.SalutationId` is set to one (I verified this by outputting the value to another control) however it doesn't select MR automatically until I change the model value within another control.

What I would like to happen is that it selects MR automatically as that is the value from the job itself.

Can anyone spot where I have gone wrong? I have also tried to update the scope manually using `$scope.$apply` to see if it had an affect but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Bit of school boy error really.

AngularJS uses the === operator in javascript to check the value and type and with the select control being string based it didn't like that my scope was using an integer value.

To resolve the problem I simply convert the lookup ID to a string value on the scope.

This shouldn't cause a problem on the API side as it will parse the string as an integer automatically.